# ASCII to binary conversion?

Tags: c++, ascii

I'm reading an ASCII file and trying to convert this to binary.

My code goes like this:

```
void AtoB(char * input)
{
 int ascii; 
int length = strlen(input);

for(int x=0;x<length;x++) 
{
    ascii = input[x];
```

here when I'm reading a single character from the file like È via line `ascii = input[x];

I'm getting value as -56 [if ascii type is int] and ascii = 4294967240 [if ascii type is unsigned int] and based on this my output is also changing.I referred ASCII table here: http://www.simotime.com/asc2ebc1.htm 
, Still unable to understand what values are these and on what basis its getting assigned to the character È

Note:I'm using Visual Studio 2010 on Win 7 64bit to write this code(This may not matter, still giving this note).**Encoding is ANSI.**

Could anyone please help me understanding this? Thanks.

[image: The screen shot of ASCII file]

Comment: Don't spam tags. C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: `È` is not an [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character. What encoding is actually used?

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/ Ascii codes has values from 0 to 255. To get it change from **int ascii;** to the **char ascii;**

Comment: https://ideone.com/R2z4UL seems to work...

Comment: Please refer this for ASCII table - http://www.simotime.com/asc2ebc1.htm. If this is not ASCII then what these characters are? the screen shot is from notepad++

Comment: @TryingBest The table is wrong. ASCII goes from 0 to 127 only. The rest may be Extended ASCII (which is not ASCII, and is not one single encoding!) or something else.

Comment: @EmbeddedDev No, ASCII goes from 0 to 127. The website you link is one of many that gets that phenomenally wrong and confuses everybody.

Comment: There is no text but encoded text. If someone gives you the bytes of a text file without the knowledge of which encoding is used, you have a failed communication. If someone gives you a file with a byte >127 and says it is ASCII, you know they don't know what they are doing. If ASCII is even mentioned without referring to a spec that explicitly calls it out, you very likely have misinformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`È` is not an [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character. Let's assume the file is actually encoded using [cp1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)<sup>[1]</sup>.

`È` encoded using cp1252 is `C8` (hex).

If you interpret `C8` as an unsigned 8-bit integer, it's 200.

If you interpret `C8` as a signed 8-bit integer, it's -56.

If you interpret `C8` as a signed 8-bit integer, then extend it to a signed 32-bit integer, then cast it to an unsigned 32-bit integer, it's 4294967240.

So you have the expected value; you are simply interpreting it differently than you intended.

---

1. The encoding used to make systems calls (the encoding of `LPCTSTR` and `LPTSTR` arguments to system calls) in a build where `UNICODE` isn't defined is called the "ANSI" encoding. The actual encoding can vary from machine to machine. However, the "ANSI" encoding for (most? all?) English-language Windows machines is cp1252.

Comment: Thanks. Added encoding in my question.Checked wiki. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

Comment: CP1252 is common. However, the default encoding for the _console_ on all versions of Windows and MS-DOS I have ever used is CP437. Go `chcp`.

Comment: @Tom Blodget, 1) cp437 is an OEM code page (used by the Console), not an ANSI code page (used for system calls). You never talk to the OS using 437. If your OEM cp is 437, I'm willing to bet your ANSI cp is 1252. 2) My OEM code page is [850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), not 437. It has always been 850 on all my machines. I think it's because something is set to Canada instead of US. cp850 has more accented letters, so it satisfies both of our official languages. 3) cp437 doesn't include `È`, so we're obviously not talking about cp437.

Answer (score 3):

According to your table, `È` is `11001000` in binary.
When `char` is signed, `11001000` is interpreted as -56.
When it's unsigned, the value is 200.

-56 in 32 bits is `11111111111111111111111111001000`, which is 4294967240 when interpreted as an unsigned integer.